# Malwarebytes Anti-Exploit and Tor

Tags: add-on

I installed Malwarebytes Anti-Exploit (free) on my PC. Malwarebytes claims that the product “wraps four layers of security around popular browsers, preventing exploits from compromising vulnerable code.” I use the Tor Browser for certain activities, for example, banking. Malwarebytes Anti-Exploit also “wraps” itself around the Tor Browser.

Could someone kindly inform me if using this add-on compromises Tor in any way and thus should not be using it?

I look forward to a response.

Thank you.